# jQuery create tables from JSON and group in expandable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom, html-table

I want to create a nested table with data from JSON file. here I use an array of object to simulate the back end:

```
 var response = [
                {
                "mezzo":"fiat punto",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"1"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"fiat punto",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"2"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"fiat punto",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"3"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"alfa giulia",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"1"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"alfa giulia",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"2"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"fiat punto",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"4"
                },
                {
                "mezzo":"alfa giulia",
                "tipologia":"auto",
                "id":"3"
                }
            ];
```

I want to group my result table using the "mezzo" field, so I try sorting the array:

```
    response.sort(function(a,b){
        var mezzoA = a.mezzo.toLowerCase();
        var mezzoB = b.mezzo.toLowerCase();
        if (mezzoA > mezzoB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (mezzoA < mezzoB) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

now the jQuery code: I try to create elements and append to the DOM using .each() loop. the commented code works with hardcoded demo, but by now I have to group the rows matching the "mezzo" field in a single expandable row:

```
$(function () {
        var parentFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();   

        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            var parentTr = document.createElement('tr');
            var parentTd = '<td><a href="#">></a></td><td>' + item.mezzo + '</td><td>' + item.tipologia + '</td><td>' + item.id +'</td>';
            parentTr.innerHTML = parentTd;
            parentFrag.appendChild(parentTr);
        })

        var parentTable = $('.parent');
            parentTable[0].appendChild(parentFrag);

        // Expand-Collapse details table
        // $('table table').hide();

        // $('td > a').on('click', function (e) {
        //     e.preventDefault();
        //     $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
        // });
    });
```

This is my html file:

```
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Mezzo</td>
            <td>Tipologia</td>
            <td>ID</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="parent">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you consider using a jQuery library to do this

Comment: No, i can't use libraries, is against company rules

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: A table with a first tbody row with The "mezzo" only shown, and when i click on This row open a nested table under with all The details rows